# Register devices in database to allow receiving ios notifications from APNS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, device

I am trying to implement push notifications in my application, and it works well on my device, when I put the devicetoken static in the php file.

Now, I want to insert all devices that install the application in a table (`apns_devices`) in my database, to allow receiving push notifications, I have a `class_APNS.php` which includes the query to insert the devices, but in this file I should put certificates. They put in the class: `private $certificate = our certificate` and another one: `private $sandboxCerficate = 'another certificate'` in fact I do not know which certificates should I put here, I have certificates with different extensions (`.cer`, `.p12`, `.pem`), and I am getting confused.

When I am running the application on the device to get the required information, it gives:

```
Register URL: http://......./apns.php?task=register&appname=myfirstapp&appversion=1.0&devicetoken=2ca0c25ed7acea73e19c9d9193e57a12c1817ed48ddf8f44baea42e68a51563c&devicemodel=iPad&deviceversion=6.1.3&pushbadge=enabled&pushalert=enabled&pushsound=enabled
```

Please can someone advice me what shall I put in this class, because the query of insertion devices in database doesn't work.

apns.php is:

```
<?PHP

// AUTOLOAD CLASS OBJECTS... YOU CAN USE INCLUDES IF YOU PREFER
if(!function_exists("__autoload")){
    function __autoload($class_name){
        require_once('class_'.$class_name.'.php');
    }
}

// CREATE DATABASE OBJECT ( MAKE SURE TO CHANGE LOGIN INFO IN CLASS FILE )
$db = new DbConnect();
$db->show_errors();

// FETCH $_GET OR CRON ARGUMENTS TO AUTOMATE TASKS
$args = (!empty($_GET)) ? $_GET:array('task'=>$argv[1]);

// CREATE APNS OBJECT, WITH DATABASE OBJECT AND ARGUMENTS
$apns = new APNS($db, $args);
?>
```

class_APNS.php is:

```
<?PHP
class APNS {
    private $db;
    private $apnsData;
    private $showErrors = true;
    private $logErrors = true;
    private $logPath = 'apns.log';
    private $logMaxSize = 1048576; // max log size before it is truncated
    // private $certificate = 'CHANGE THIS';
    private $ssl = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
    private $feedback = 'ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196';
    private $sandboxCertificate = 'apns-dev.pem';
    private $sandboxSsl = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
    private $sandboxFeedback = 'ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196';
    private $message;

    function __construct($db, $args=NULL) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->checkSetup();
        $this->apnsData = array(
            'production'=>array(
                'certificate'=>$this->certificate,
                'ssl'=>$this->ssl,
                'feedback'=>$this->feedback
            ),
            'sandbox'=>array(
                'certificate'=>$this->sandboxCertificate,
                'ssl'=>$this->sandboxSsl,
                'feedback'=>$this->sandboxFeedback
            )
        );
        if(!empty($args)){
            switch($args['task']){
                case "register":
                    $this->_registerDevice(
                        $args['appname'],
                        $args['appversion'],
                        $args['deviceuid'],
                        $args['devicetoken'],
                        $args['devicename'],
                        $args['devicemodel'],
                        $args['deviceversion'],
                        $args['pushbadge'],
                        $args['pushalert'],
                        $args['pushsound']
                    );
                    break;

                case "fetch";
                    $this->_fetchMessages();
                    break;

                default:
                    echo "No APNS Task Provided...\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private function checkSetup(){
        if(!file_exists($this->certificate)) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Missing Production Certificate.', E_USER_ERROR);
        if(!file_exists($this->sandboxCertificate)) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Missing Sandbox Certificate.', E_USER_ERROR);

        clearstatcache();
        $certificateMod = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($this->certificate)), -3);
        $sandboxCertificateMod = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($this->sandboxCertificate)), -3); 

        if($certificateMod>644)  $this->_triggerError('NOTICE: Production Certificate is insecure! Suggest chmod 644.');
        if($sandboxCertificateMod>644)  $this->_triggerError('NOTICE: Sandbox Certificate is insecure! Suggest chmod 644.');
    }

    private function _registerDevice($appname, $appversion, $deviceuid, $devicetoken, $devicename, $devicemodel, $deviceversion, $pushbadge, $pushalert, $pushsound){

        if(strlen($appname)==0) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Application Name must not be blank.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($appversion)==0) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Application Version must not be blank.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($deviceuid)!=40) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Device ID must be 40 characters in length.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($devicetoken)!=64) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Device Token must be 64 characters in length.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($devicename)==0) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Device Name must not be blank.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($devicemodel)==0) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Device Model must not be blank.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if(strlen($deviceversion)==0) $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Device Version must not be blank.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if($pushbadge!='disabled' && $pushbadge!='enabled') $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Push Badge must be either Enabled or Disabled.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if($pushalert!='disabled' && $pushalert!='enabled') $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Push Alert must be either Enabled or Disabled.', E_USER_ERROR);
        else if($pushsound!='disabled' && $pushsound!='enabled') $this->_triggerError('ERROR: Push Sount must be either Enabled or Disabled.', E_USER_ERROR);

        $appname = $this->db->prepare($appname);
        $appversion = $this->db->prepare($appversion);
        $deviceuid = $this->db->prepare($deviceuid);
        $devicetoken = $this->db->prepare($devicetoken);
        $devicename = $this->db->prepare($devicename);
        $devicemodel = $this->db->prepare($devicemodel);
        $deviceversion = $this->db->prepare($deviceversion);
        $pushbadge = $this->db->prepare($pushbadge);
        $pushalert = $this->db->prepare($pushalert);
        $pushsound = $this->db->prepare($pushsound);

        // store device for push notifications
        $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); // force utf8 encoding if not your default
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `apns_devices`
                VALUES (
                    NULL,
                    '{$appname}',
                    '{$appversion}',
                    '{$deviceuid}',
                    '{$devicetoken}',
                    '{$devicename}',
                    '{$devicemodel}',
                    '{$deviceversion}',
                    '{$pushbadge}',
                    '{$pushalert}',
                    '{$pushsound}',
                    'production',
                    'active',
                    NOW(),
                    NOW()
                )
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `devicetoken`='{$devicetoken}',
                `devicename`='{$devicename}',
                `devicemodel`='{$devicemodel}',
                `deviceversion`='{$deviceversion}',
                `pushbadge`='{$pushbadge}',
                `pushalert`='{$pushalert}',
                `pushsound`='{$pushsound}',
                `status`='active',
                `modified`=NOW();";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
private function _unregisterDevice($token){
        $sql = "UPDATE `apns_devices`
                SET `status`='uninstalled'
                WHERE `devicetoken`='{$token}'
                LIMIT 1;";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you use EasyAPNS?? I have same problema. How you solve this?